# Altering $scope controller variables on URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have a simple web app that is just a table with formatted JSON data. When you click on a column, you can filter that column in ascending order.

I would like for actions like that to change the url to something like:

www.website.com/column/asc,

that way you can send the link and when you visit it, the column is automatically sorted in ascending order. I have been trying to find a way to do this, and the closest I came was ui.router.

However, I need to alter a controller scope variable, which I cannot do from the app.config, am I missing something? Is there a better way of accomplishing what I need?

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        $stateProvider.state(keys[i],{
            url:'/'+keys[i],
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.search = {keys[i]:ascending};
            }
        })
    }

}]);
```

Unfortunately, from here, i'm not sure where I should proceed. Most of the documentation uses template pages, and I just want a controller variable to change. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into defining URL parameters with UI-router and then you inject the $stateParams service into your controller so you can read the parameters from the URL.

Start by defining your states like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('search',{
    url: '/search/:searchParam',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.search = $stateParams.searchParam;
    }
});
```

Note that I've changed the URL format slightly. The URL is prefixed with a unique string ('search') and then followed by a variable parameter ':searchParam'.

Also, we are only defining one state called 'search', instead of one state per parameter.

So with the above the url: '/search/asc' will route to the 'search' state, and `$stateParams.searchParam` will evaluate to 'asc'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).

Just set a param in your url by calling:

```
$location.search(keys[i]: 'ascending');
```